# Error when trying to install mod_jk - Centos 8

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk, centos8

I'm a Digitalocean user and I'm trying to migrate mi infraestructre from Centos 7 to Centos 8
It implies moving DBs (mysql), set a Web Server and Java.
One of the steps is installing Apache and Tomcat making use of mod_jk.
All the steps I will describe end in a complete succes in Centos 7 but fails in Centos 8
The way i got Java installed was by a RPM package I downloaded from oracle itself.

```
# java -version
java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

These are all the steps I follow.

```
# dnf install httpd
#cd /tmp
# wget https://apache.zero.com.ar/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/tomcat-connectors-1.2.48-src.tar.gz
# cd tomcat-connectors-1.2.48-src/native
# dnf install httpd-devel
# dnf install make
# dnf install libtool
# which apxs
/usr/bin/apxs
```

In this directory there's the file "BUILDING.txt" with instructions to install which I follow.
It looks like this.

```
# ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/bin/apxs
# make
```

And here there is seem to be the problem.
Some "redhat" directory not found in Centos.

[Error when executing 'Make' screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2F09.png)

The next would be

```
# make install
```

But is fails in Centos 8

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All this process is successful in Centos 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install redhat-rpm-config. Install redhat-rpm-config and test.

```
yum install redhat-rpm-config
```